# Enabling automatic cookie addition

Tags: http, go, cookies, request

I am developing a web scraping project which requires for me to send requests to certain pages of a website. As it stands, from what I can see using my web debugger, I have to send requests to the home page of the site in order to get a response with certain cookies which I would need to access other parts of the site. This is necessary for me currently because I would have to manually add cookies from the response headers which can be a pain.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to specify a cookie "jar" for your http client, which will provide a persistent cookie location that will be sent by client requests and updated based on cookie headers in the response:

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cookiejar/#example_New